# How to block an IP for a specific site on a server with multiple sites

Tags: nginx, blacklist, whitelist

There's something hitting a server I'm looking at a rapid rate and it's taking the site down. It's doing ...

```
POST /index.php/api/v2_soap/ HTTP/1.1, host: dev.mysite.com
```

I'd like to block all IPs to `dev.mysite.com` except for my IP.

I have the Nginx config file here: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. [1]

I have the site-specific file here: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dev-mysite`. [2]

I've tried the below in [2].

```
location / {
    ... # some other stuff
    allow 172.xx.xx.xx; # my IP   
    deny all;
  }
```

and it's blocking all traffic to `dev.mysite.com` except mine, but the POST request is still coming through, unless I configure the below in [1].

```
http {
    ...
    deny 216.xxx.xxx.xxx; # offending IP
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to modify just file [2] and achieve what I'm trying to do (deny all traffic except from my IP)?

Comment: I would just add this into fail2ban.

Comment: @MichaelHampton He just want to block all IP's except the IP he has.
he should try using .htaccess:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/deny-all-allow-only-one-ip-through-htaccess

Comment: Have you tried [2] in the `server` block rather than in the `location` block?

Comment: Why don't you just create an iptables entry, no need to fiddle with your webserver at all. Because if you don't block it at the Kernel-level (aka iptables) the request will still come through to your webserver which then has to handle it. htaccess is not a firewall. So either block the specific IP (favorable automate it with fail2ban like @MichaelHampton said) or block all IPs but your own.